# Split Array of Objects using a key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data array like below which needs to be a structured by using Value property with Start and End Time

```
[{
        "Timestamp": "2021-09-30T21:38:46.7000122Z",
        "Value": "496",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-01T01:08:47.4690093Z",
        "Value": "496",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-02T15:38:02.5080108Z",
        "Value": "207",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-02T16:30:32.3410034Z",
        "Value": "207",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-02T21:45:32.7460021Z",
        "Value": "207",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-02T22:38:02.5839996Z",
        "Value": "413",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-02T23:30:33.3980102Z",
        "Value": "413",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-03T00:23:02.7130126Z",
        "Value": "413",
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2021-10-03T11:47:47.8630065Z",
        "Value": "413",
    }]
```

Is there a way to compose the above array to into below format like group using Value and pick the the 1st object timestamp as Start Time and last object timestamp value as End Time like below

```
[{
"id": 496
"stTime": "2021-09-30T21:38:46.7000122Z"
"endTime": "2021-10-01T01:08:47.4690093Z"
},{
"id": 207
"stTime": "2021-10-02T15:38:02.5080108Z"
"endTime": "2021-10-02T21:45:32.7460021Z"
},{
"id": 413
"stTime": "2021-10-02T22:38:02.5839996Z"
"endTime": "2021-10-03T11:47:47.8630065Z"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-09-30T21:38:46.7000122Z",
    Value: "496",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-01T01:08:47.4690093Z",
    Value: "496",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-02T15:38:02.5080108Z",
    Value: "207",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-02T16:30:32.3410034Z",
    Value: "207",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-02T21:45:32.7460021Z",
    Value: "207",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-02T22:38:02.5839996Z",
    Value: "413",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-02T23:30:33.3980102Z",
    Value: "413",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-03T00:23:02.7130126Z",
    Value: "413",
  },
  {
    Timestamp: "2021-10-03T11:47:47.8630065Z",
    Value: "413",
  },
];


function processTimestamps(timestamps) {
  return timestamps.reduce((retval, { Timestamp, Value }) => {
    const currTime = new Date(Timestamp)
    const existing = retval.find(obj => obj.id === Value)
    if(existing){
      const startTime = new Date(existing.stTime)
      const endTime = new Date(existing.endTime)
      if (currTime < startTime){
        existing.startTime = Timestamp
      }
      if (currTime > endTime){
        existing.endTime = Timestamp
      }
    }else{
      retval.push({
        id: Value,
        stTime: Timestamp,
        endTime: Timestamp
      })
    }
    return retval
  }, []);
}

console.log(processTimestamps(data));
```

Comment: This can be refactored to be better/clearer, but it works.

Comment: Consider that for all `timestamps` elements you are doing `Array#find()` and that works but is not performant

Comment: @YosvelQuinteroArguelles: You are correct. As I said in my comment, it could be refactored to be better. I really just wanted to push the idea of comparing min/max of current timestamp in a "brute force" way to simplify these kinds of problems in the future. I was originally going to use a Math.min/Math.max solution but I thought it might be hard to understand.

Comment: @YosvelQuinteroArguelles: I like your Object.values solution for avoiding Array.find

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to extract the values `result` array of [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)ing the `data`.

Code:

```js
const data = [{Timestamp: '2021-09-30T21:38:46.7000122Z',Value: '496',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-01T01:08:47.4690093Z',Value: '496',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T15:38:02.5080108Z',Value: '207',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T16:30:32.3410034Z',Value: '207',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T21:45:32.7460021Z',Value: '207',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T22:38:02.5839996Z',Value: '413',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T23:30:33.3980102Z',Value: '413',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-03T00:23:02.7130126Z',Value: '413',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-03T11:47:47.8630065Z',Value: '413'}]

const result = Object
  .values(
    data.reduce((a, { Value, Timestamp }) => {
      a[Value] = a[Value] || {
        id: +Value,
        stTime: Timestamp,
      }
      a[Value].endTime = Timestamp
      return a
    }, {})
  )

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [{Timestamp: '2021-09-30T21:38:46.7000122Z',Value: '496',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-01T01:08:47.4690093Z',Value: '496',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T15:38:02.5080108Z',Value: '207',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T16:30:32.3410034Z',Value: '207',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T21:45:32.7460021Z',Value: '207',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T22:38:02.5839996Z',Value: '413',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-02T23:30:33.3980102Z',Value: '413',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-03T00:23:02.7130126Z',Value: '413',},{Timestamp: '2021-10-03T11:47:47.8630065Z',Value: '413'}]

var res = data.map(e=>e.Value).filter((e,i,a)=>a.indexOf(e)==i).map(e=>({id:e,times:time.filter(x=>x.Value==e).map(x=>x.Timestamp)}))
.map(e=>({t:e,s:new Date(e)})).sort((a,b)=>a.s-b.s > 1).map(e=>e.t)
.map(e=>({id:e.id,stTime:e.times.shift(),endTime:e.times.pop()}))
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).